# How do I get my MacTeX version?

Tags: command-line, latex, mactex

If I wanted to report a bug, how could I find my MacTeX version via command line?

Comment: See [Checking MacTeX version installed on a Mac](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7295/5764).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the MacTeX Support [Mailing List](http://mactex-support@tug.org):

> Howdy,
>
> Try running
>
> `pdflatex --version`
>
> in Terminal. The first of many lines it returns gives the TeX Live
>   version which is also the MacTeX version. E.g. I get
>
> `pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012) ...`
>
> since I'm using TeX Live 2012 and therefore MacTeX-2012.
>
> Good Luck,
>
> Herb Schulz

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
cd /usr/texbin
pwd -P
```

Otherwise, you can see the version through MacTeX's preference pane, which is automatically added to System Preferences upon installation.

Answer (score 1):

Find the installer "MacTeX-2xxx.pkg" and get info.  The version number is listed.